# How do I get values of the second, third, nth pass in a django template for loop?

Tags: python, django

I have the following code in my template:

```
{% with element=vals|first %} #can use last here to get the last value
    {% for key,value in element.items %}
        <td>{{ value.corr }}</td>
        <td>{{ value.str }}</td>
        <td>{{ value.sig }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

That will give me the first values in the first iteration of the loop.

How do I get the second, third, and nth?

I'd thought about using slice, but that doesn't seem to work here -- or I'm not formatting the slice correctly.

Please help!

EDIT: my list of dicts:

```
[{('age', 'after'): 
        {'str': 'one', 'sig': 'two', 'cor': 'three'}
    }, 
{('age', 'before'): 
        {'str': 'zero', 'sig': 'one', 'cor': 'four'}
    }, 
{('exp', 'after'): 
        {'str': 'one', 'sig': 'two', 'cor': 'three'}
    },   
{('exp', 'before'): 
        {'str': 'zero', 'sig': 'one', 'cor': 'four'}
}]
```

EDIT 2: Desired output

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Parameters</th>
            <th>Pos/Neg</th>
            <th>Str</th>
            <th>Sig</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">First Table Row</th>
                {% with element=q3vals|first %}
                    {% for key,value in element.items %}
                        {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
                            <td>{{ value.corr }}</td>
                            <td>{{ value.str }}</td>
                            <td>{{ value.sig }}</td>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endwith %}
        </tr>
        <tr>#second loop through the list of dicts</tr>
        <tr>#third loop through the list of dicts
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Fourth Table Row</th>
                {% with element=q3vals|last %} #last loop through
                    {% for key,value in element.items %}
                        <td>{{ value.corr }}</td>
                        <td>{{ value.str }}</td>
                        <td>{{ value.sig }}</td>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endwith %}      
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If any of the below answers helped you then mark it as accepted please. It's a good practice in StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`forloop.counter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#for) for that.

```
{% with element=vals|first %} {# can use last here to get the last value #}
    {% for key,value in element.items %}
        {% if forloop.counter == 2 %}  {# or if forloop.first etc. #}
            <td>{{ value.corr }}</td>
            <td>{{ value.str }}</td>
            <td>{{ value.sig }}</td>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

[EDIT]:

```
{% for dict in q3vals %}
    {% for key, inner_dict in dict.items %}
    {# key, each time, will be ('age', 'after'), ('age', 'before') etc #}
    {# inner_dict, each time, will be {'str': 'one', 'sig': 'two', 'cor': 'three'} etc #}
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Table Row #{{ forloop.counter }}</th>
            <td>{{ inner_dict.cor }}</td>
            <td>{{ inner_dict.str }}</td>
            <td>{{ inner_dict.sig }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: As it start from zeroth index, so it should be `forloop.counter0` right ?

Comment: No. `forloop.counter` starts from 1. If you want to start from 0 then use `forloop.counter0` and do `{% if forloop.counter0 == 1 %}` (this will be the second element).

Comment: @nik_m must be doing something incorrectly: My list of dicts looks like my as edit above. The {% with .. |first %} statement gives me the first set of values. But I don't know what sort of filter to use with the "with" statement to get the second.

Comment: How exactly you want the output formatted? Show an example please.

Comment: @nik_m edited to show preferred output: see above & thanks!

Comment: @nik_m Thanks, very much! I see what I was doing wrong. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to official doc (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/language/#variables), you need to try the for loop like this:

```
{% for k, v in defaultdict.iteritems %}
    Do something with k and v here...
{% endfor %}
```

Hence, your code should be:

```
 {% for key,value in element.iteritems %}
```

Hope it will help.